# How to turn off multiple light one by one in blender

Tags: lighting

[image]i got a scene where i have a long corridor (infini corridor) with arround 100 lights all the way and i wanted to turn them off one by one (not all at the same time)
If you have any ideas

Let me know

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use an array of objects with emission on them and keyframe the array count?

Comment: This is so smart thanks you !!

Comment: I think @moonboots idea is better because you can set the light direction and area as you wish, but unfortuately you can't use modifiers with lights so can't use an array of them. :^(

Comment: does it have to be lights? or can it also be a mesh with e.g. emission shader (which is a light too)?

Comment: As John and Chris say, it will be easier if your lights are an object with Emission (in Cycles)

Answer (score 3):

A bit tedious but you could create one light, give 2 keyframes to its *Power* so that it goes from on to off:

[image]

It won't create an action per se but you can push the animation in the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, it will appear as an orange strip:

[image]

Then duplicate the light as many time as you want and shift the strips of the copies:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I make no secret of it that i am a big fan of animation nodes. It's a free add-on and worth every minute learning it.

So if you install it, you can use this easy node setup:

[image]

and you will get:

[image]